# Non-square data array distorted when using InterpolationOrder->0 in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I am trying to fit a list `{{x1,y1,f1},{x2,y2,f2},...}` with `ListDensityPlot`. The tricky part is that for a fixed x, the list does not have the same step size in y. I would like to not interpolate the plot, but when I use `InterpolationOrder -> 0`, the plot fixes data range to the maximum value.

Here is an example to illustrate it

```
ListDensityPlot[{
{1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4},
{2, 0.5, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 3.5, 5},
{3, 0.75, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 3.25, 0}
}]
```

which yields

[image]

Adding `InterpolationOrder->0` results in

```
ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 0.5, 1}, {2, 2, 
   2}, {2, 3.5, 5}, {3, 0.75, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 3.25, 0}}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

Is there an easy way to not interpolate the data, but also avoid getting it distorted?

Thanks,
Sole

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by distortion in this case?

Comment: Well, for example, the data point at {1,3} gets pushed to {1,3.5} when using `InterpolationOrder->0`, which is not a true coordinate of that data point.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean this?

```
pts = {{1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4}, {2, 0.5, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 
    3.5, 5}, {3, 0.75, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 3.25, 0}};
R = ConvexHullMesh[pts[[All, 1 ;; 2]]];
ListDensityPlot[pts,
 InterpolationOrder -> 0,
 RegionFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] RegionMember[R][{x, y}])
 ]
```

[image]

Note that `ListDensityPlot` colors always full [Voronoi cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) with respect to the point cloud `pts`. That actually quite meaningful.